# CSS/JavaScript not getting loaded inextended URL created using wordpress path based multisite network

Tags: wordpress, apache, mod-rewrite

Need assistance here with respect to rewrite rules of `apache httpd`.

The issue is with configuring `multisite` using `wordpress`. We are able to successfully create an `extended URL` using path based multisite feature of `wordpress`.  The extended URL is

```
http://www.example.com.au/support/
```

The issue with the `extended URL` is that it is not loading the `CSS/Java Scripts` when loading the `extended URL`. That's why the UI looks broken for `extended URL`.  It looks like it is not able to load the files where the `CSS/Java` scripts are available. This I am telling from the contents of access log file as shown below.

`10.200.64.39 "-" - - [02/Nov/2015:00:29:37 +1100] "GET /support/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/js/functions.js?ver=20150330 HTTP/1.1" 404 9402 "http://www.example.com.au/support/wp-admin/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0" 39020 "-" "Cookies:wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check;`

It is showing `404 not found` for the following file

`GET /support/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/js/functions.js?ver=20150330 HTTP/1.1"`

```
 $ ls -l  /support/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/js/functions.js
ls: cannot access /support/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/js/functions.js: No such file or directory

 $ ls -l  wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/js/functions.js
 -rwxrwxrwx 1 nobody admin 5899 Jul 30 04:13 wp-content/themes /twentyfifteen/js/functions.js`

 $ pwd
 /data/share/web/marketing/digitalsol
 $ ls -ld wp-content/ wp-includes/ wp-admin/
   drwxrwsrwx  9 nobody admin 4096 Sep 16 00:58 wp-admin/
   drwxrwsrwx  5 nobody admin 4096 Oct 30 22:13 wp-content/
   drwxrwsrwx 12 nobody admin 4096 Sep 16 00:58 wp-includes/
```

The issue with the extended URL is the support directory which is a part of `extended URL` but this directory does not physically exist on system.

So , probably we need to modify the `rewrite` rules so that it can load the `CSS/javascript` in the `extended URL`. Shown below is the current rewrite rules available.

```
$ cat .htaccess
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Please suggest in resolving the issue

Comment: WordPress should be able to handle this on its own. Did you set up this htaccess file, or was the content generated by WP (it should be the latter)? Also, setting up a multisite requires some additional code to be copy&pasted into the config file, did you do that?

Comment: yes..it was the content generated by WP . Also added additional code to wp-config.php

Comment: Also , I noticed that If I create the support directory manually and copy the wp-content/admin/includes into this directory , then CSS/Java Script are loaded in the extended URL but if i open the wordpress admin link for extended URL ( wp-admin link) after this modification it shows blank page

Answer (score 0):

In the apache configuration file , we had `wp_security.conf`  which was enabled.This configuration file contains ACLs to deny `.htaccess` from ALL. On commenting the ACL entry , CSS/JS are loading fine in extended multisite URL.